# MyPy, VSCode, Django, ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, mypy

I am working on a Django project. I want to be able to check the types in my project. For this purpose, I have installed django-stubs and mypy. Moreover, I want it to work with the VSCode extension. It saves time because I don't have to run mypy in terminal every time I have to check everything. However, MyPy simply crashes because it cannot find Django settings for some reason..... I have already tried moving around the mypy.ini file. It does not help. BTW, it works if I run MyPy in terminal.

Error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_project.settings'`

mypy.ini:

```
[mypy]
plugins = mypy_django_plugin.main, mypy_drf_plugin.main


[mypy.plugins.django-stubs]
django_settings_module = "my_project.settings"
```

settings.json:

```
{
    "python.linting.mypyEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
    "mypy.runUsingActiveInterpreter": true,
    "mypy.configFile":"my_project/mypy.ini",
    "mypy.targets":[
        "."
    ]
}
```

wsgi.py:

```
"""
WSGI config for web_app project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

```
myvenv
|
|
.vscode
|  |--settings.json
|
my_project
|  |--mypy.ini
|  |--my_project
|     |
|     |--settings.py
|
|
```

Comment: Have a look at workarounds [in this issue] (https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/134). I don't use vscode, so shouldn't give an answer and cannot test that, but if you succeed, it would be great to answer your own question with the solution for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the solution was not obvious, but I got it. To solve it you need to move the mypy.ini file one folder back and include the `mypy_path = ./my_project` line into the mypy.ini. Include this configuration under the `[mypy]` section.

I found the idea for the solution here:

https://github.com/typeddjango/django-stubs/issues/134

Enjoy the VSCode with MyPy. I hope they will include better docs later!!!

Comment: Here are the relevant [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-mypy_path)

Comment: This comment saved me after 2 or 3 hours of not finding the issue. In my case, I was just missing the `mypy_path` instruction.

Comment: Actually, there is no need to move the config file (mypy.ini or other). "_Relative paths are treated relative to the working directory of the mypy command, not the config file._" In case you want it to be relative to config file, you can use `$MYPY_CONFIG_FILE_DIR` e.g. `mypy_path = $MYPY_CONFIG_FILE_DIR/src`
Source: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html?highlight=mypy_path#confval-mypy_path